# Clustering with N nodes and K distribution centers

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, load-balancing, heuristics

I have a **data set** of `N` **nodes** and `K` **distribution centers**. If I know their respective (x,y) **coordinates**

> What algorithm can I use to cluster these nodes keeping the balance
>   between the distance node-center and number of nodes assigned to the
>   centers?

For example, I could use as criteria, assign the nodes to their nearest center of distribution but this could produce **distribution centers with many nodes**, and I want to avoid this. Any help?

Comment: Could be written as a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming problem). Something like an assignment problem,

Comment: How much more important is it that the nodes be well-distributed vs close to their "warehouse"? Consider a contrived an example with 2 warehouses, and N-1 nodes are close to warehouse A, and only 1 node close to B. When do we connect nodes to B?

Comment: You are right Erwin, that was the first technique and worked very good but I'm experimenting with faster methods sacrificing the best answer, for that reason, a MIP is no more an option for me. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: That's the point Larry, I'm searching for approximations to the best answer. Would be good to see how work different approaches to solve this situation being this a corner case. Sometimes it will prefer the minimum distance over the balance or not. If in your case the algorithm match N-1 nodes to A and only one to B for me is good, or if it try to balance some nodes also is good. Suppose that I'm searching something like a K-means approaching to my centers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to define what "balance" means before you can come up with an algorithm to achieve it. You have to decide how much more (or less) important proximity to the node is in relation to having approximately equal numbers of nodes per distribution center. Perhaps you want the ability to tweak that, so that you can set the relative importance and have the algorithm come as close as possible. But without more detailed requirements, it will be difficult to give you a  meaningful answer.

Comment: For i = N..N/k I would solve the assignment problem to minimise the total sum of distances subject to the constraint that no distribution center serves more than i nodes. Then draw a graph of the costs and decide how even a distribution I really want.

Answer (score 1):

Formulate this as an optimization problem.

E.g. average distance, and a penalty factor when too many N are assigned to the same K.

Then use a standard optimization technique to find a solution.

Don't expect anything out of the box to support vague constraints like yours. You have to decide on what a good solution is, then have an optimizer search a good solution.